# Create tuple from dictionary defined from list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I'm using python 3.5, I have a dictionary:

```
dict =  {1:'entry 1', 2:'entry 2', 3:'entry 3', 4:'entry 4'}
```

and a list:

```
numlist = [1,3,4]
```

What I want is to create a tuple from the dictionary based on the items in the list. So in the above example my desired output is:

```
('entry 1','entry 3','entry 4')
```

I'm not sure how to do this however. I tried:

```
templist = ()
for i in numlist:
    templist = (dict[i]) + templist
```

However this through up a "TypeError: Can't convert 'tuple' object to str implicitly"

I'm not sure how else to handle this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## what about using list comprehension?

```
tuple([dict[e] for e in numlist])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
>>> tuple((dict[num] for num in numlist))
('entry 1', 'entry 3', 'entry 4')
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept your solution even if it is not pythonic way:

```
dict =  {1:'entry 1', 2:'entry 2', 3:'entry 3', 4:'entry 4'}
    numlist = [1,3,4]
    templist = ()
    for i in numlist:
        templist = (dict[i],) + templist

    print templist
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehensions:`tuple([dict[x] for x in numlist])`